# in YAML how to passing multiple arguments to powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

```
- task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'filepath'
            filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/psscript.ps1
            arguments: >
              -ContainerName $(ContainerName
              **-Url $(Url) + '&sub-key=' + $(SubscriptionKey)**
          displayName: 'Uploading files'
```

-URL is not working
error  | You must provide a value expression following the '+' operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```yaml
jobs:
- job:
  variables:
    a: $[format('{0}"&"sub-key={1}', variables.Url, variables.SubscriptionKey)]
  steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'filepath'
        filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/psscript.ps1
        arguments: >
            -ContainerName $(ContainerName)
            -Url $(a)
      displayName: 'Uploading files'
```

Comment: Thank you,  variables.SubscriptionKey  this is actually coming form keyvault not form the variable

Comment: It is still mapped to variable.`$(SubscriptionKey)` this is nothing more than secret variable.

Comment: getting the below error
The term 'sub-key=' is not recognized as a name of a
     | cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.

Comment: Did you fix my mistake here `$[format('{0}&sub-key={1}', variables.Url, variables.SubscriptionKey)]` i missed one parenthesis

Comment: yes i fixed this after that i am getting sub-key=' is not recognized as a name of a | cmdlet

Comment: a: $[format('{0}&sub-key={1}', variables.Url, variables.SubscriptionKey)]

if i remove &  from &sub-key it is working fine  i need to add && in the format

Comment: a: $[format('{0}"&"sub-key={1}', variables.Url, variables.SubscriptionKey)]
"&" worked for me Thank you

Comment: Cool. I edited my answer to change the pattern. Could you consider accepting my reply as answer?